# Pyspark: grouby by different days

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe that looks like the following

```
df.show(5)
+--------------------+-------------------+
|                  ID|                day|
+--------------------+-------------------+
|ff9ff975-b46b-4ec...|2020-03-06 00:00:00|
|8fb35812-9ed4-4d0...|2020-03-06 00:00:00|
|68fafbd3-2bb9-40f...|2020-03-06 00:00:00|
|00649d8b-d254-4b7...|2020-03-06 00:00:00|
|e4a4ab3c-3263-4d4...|2020-03-06 00:00:00|
+--------------------+-------------------+
```

I would like to count for each user: the number of days that appear and the total number of appearances.

Answer (score 2):

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
import pyspark.sql.types as pst
```

First, to be sure you are working with day, convert timestamp column to date (skip this step if your column is of `DateType`)

```py
df = df.withColumn('date', psf.to_date('day', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
```

Then,

```py
(df.groupBy('ID')
   .agg(psf.sum(psf.lit(1)).alias('nobs'),
                psf.countDistinct(psf.col('day')).alias('ndays')
        )
)
```

Note: Initial proposition was using `sumDistinct`, that was a mistake ; `countDistinct` should be used

## Example

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([("ff9ff975-b46b-4ec","2020-03-06 00:00:00"),
                           ("ff9ff975-b46b-4ec","2020-03-06 00:00:00")],
                           ['ID','day'])
df = df.withColumn('date', psf.to_date('day', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
(df.groupBy('ID')
   .agg(psf.sum(psf.lit(1)).alias('nobs'),
                psf.countDistinct(psf.col('date')).alias('ndays')
        )
 .show(2)
)
+-----------------+----+-----+
|               ID|nobs|ndays|
+-----------------+----+-----+
|ff9ff975-b46b-4ec|   2|    1|
+-----------------+----+-----+
```